# Letter in quotation

Tags: quoting, letters

I want to put entire letter as a quotation in text (which is a book), something similar to what you get with `quotation` enviroinment, but preserving positions of adress etc. How to do this?

Comment: By "letter", are you referring to a single character, or a full page? For the latter, if you have an electronic version (in PDF) of the document, you could include it using `\includegraphics[page=?,..]{filename.pdf}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to process the letter separately to a pdf and then use the [pdfpages package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) to include the entire letter as a pdf. you can then scale the letter to fit whatever space you have. The package also works for multiple pages.